# RedGate ants memory profiler, Failed to create compatible device context

Tags: c#, memory

What does this error mean? Failed to create compatible device context
We have a aspx page which calls a webservice. The webservice in turns called 3rd API with Hyland. The error happens in the third party API
I have contacted their API support. They are slow to respond and since this happens in production I am wondering if there is a fix or somehow lighten the impact? Is it memory related.

I got a dump and opened it in ants memory profile dump. This is not a snapshot. I am finding memory leaks. What does this mean? Is red bad. Does it really have 589 instances. I clicked on the system.Byte[] 2.31MB and see this instance list.
Why would it have so many 4120 in the instance list? Is it really creating all these instances.

Could this be the problem? I have a routine like this. This is a asp.net webpage which calls a webservice. The webservice calls a class Provider.GetDocumentData().

```
public static  byte[] GetDocumentData(Application obApp, ParametersList parameters, ref PropertiesList Properties, ref KeywordPropertiesList Keywords)
{
    var type = "";
    var BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
    var byteData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    long documentId = 0;
    PageRangeSet pageRangeSet = null;
    var docQuery = obApp.Core.CreateDocumentQuery();
    var pageRanges = "";
    //get the content type andd DocumentId from paramters
    foreach (var paramter in parameters)
    {
        if (paramter.Key == GetDocumentDataRequest.DocumentID)
        {
            documentId = Convert.ToInt64(paramter.Value);
        }
        if (paramter.Key == GetDocumentDataRequest.PageRange)
        {
            pageRanges = paramter.Value;
        }
        if (paramter.Key.Contains(GetDocumentDataRequest.ContentType))
        {
            type = paramter.Value;
        }
    }
    var document = obApp.Core.GetDocumentByID(documentId);
    if (document != null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pageRanges))
        {
            pageRanges = "1-10000";
        }
        if (type == "text/plain")
        {
            var textProvider = obApp.Core.Retrieval.Text;
            var documentdata = document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision;

            pageRangeSet = textProvider.CreatePageRangeSet(pageRanges);
            var newpagecharacter = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[]
            {
                '\f'
            });
            var newPageStream = new MemoryStream(newpagecharacter);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var pageDataList = textProvider.GetPages(documentdata, pageRangeSet))
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pageDataList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (var newStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            var pageData = pageDataList[i];
                            pageData.Stream.CopyTo(newStream);
                            newStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            newPageStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            newStream.CopyTo(ms);
                            newPageStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        }
                    }
                    byteData = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (type == "application/pdf")
        {
            var pdfProvider = obApp.Core.Retrieval.PDF;
            var documentdata = document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision;
            var pageData = pdfProvider.GetDocument(documentdata);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pageData.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
                byteData = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        else if (type == "image/tiff")
        {
            var imageProvider = obApp.Core.Retrieval.Image;
            var documentdata = document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision;
            var pageData = imageProvider.GetDocument(documentdata);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pageData.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
                byteData = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var defaultProvider = obApp.Core.Retrieval.Default;
            var documentdata = document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision;
            pageRangeSet = defaultProvider.CreatePageRangeSet(pageRanges);
            var newpagecharacter = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[]
            {
                '\f'
            });
            var newPageStream = new MemoryStream(newpagecharacter);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var pageDataList = defaultProvider.GetPages(documentdata, pageRangeSet))
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pageDataList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (var newStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            var pageData = pageDataList[i];
                            pageData.Stream.CopyTo(newStream);
                            newStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            newPageStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            newStream.CopyTo(ms);
                            newPageStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        }
                    }
                    byteData = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return byteData;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Including some code and a failing stack (/stacks) might help us help you.  A "device context" is usually a Windows GDI thing (i.e., it's something that is used to write to a window in a Windows UI app). It could be that your third party API expects to run interactively (and expects to be able to write to a screen). But that's a guess. You'd likely see this in a failing stack listing.

Comment: @Flydog57: I added some code and screenshot of a memory dump. Can you please suggest?

Comment: `var byteData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];` This line can be removed as you're throwing away this array instance 3 lines later.

Comment: I'm completely confused. Are you getting that error message from Ants (that's how your question reads). What I was talking about was seeing a "stack trace". That shows what functions were calling which functions when your error happened. Depending on your runtime environment, you should be able to get a failing stack recorded somewhere

Comment: @Amy: Thank you. Any comments on the screenshots from Ants?

Comment: @Flydog57: The error "Failed to create compatible device contex" happens in the asp.net application. Dump is just some of my research to find any memory leaks

Comment: @Amy: I needed to initialize bytedate because of the if, then  else statements and return bytedata